# Liquibase: Change column to an autoincrement column (identity) in DB2

Tags: java, spring, db2, liquibase

I'm trying to change a BIGINT Column to an autoincremented column in DB2 but I can't seem find how.
I tried doing it like this:

```
    <changeSet id="08.01" author="...">
        <addColumn tableName="table_name">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>

            <column name="member_type" type="varchar(100)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="08.02" author="...">
        <addAutoIncrement tableName="table_name"
                          columnDataType="bigint"
                          columnName="id"/>
    </changeSet>
```

and when it runs I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/08-separation.xml::08.01::author:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=72, DRIVER=4.13.127 [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE SCHEMATEST.table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY]
    at org.springframework.bean
...
...
...
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/08separation.xml::08.01::author:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=72, DRIVER=4.13.127 [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE SCHEMATEST.table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY]
...
...
...
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=72, DRIVER=4.13.127
```

Comment: Do you want it to be a primary key?

Comment: yes but not necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An identity column cannot be nullable, this is what the [error message tells you](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0270n):

> A nullable column cannot be changed to become an identity
>            column.

Change the column constraint to `nullable="false"` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself at [this link](http://www.channeldb2.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-add-identity-column-to) and the explanation is this:

> Every DB2 admin discovers sooner or later that DB2 can not add
>   identity column to existing table easily. Following statements fails
>   due to syntax error: alter table public.clicks add column id integer
>   generated always as identity   But i have good news for everyone. It
>   can be still done, but it requires more steps.

1. Add **not null integer** column
   You need to provide default value for it otherwise db2 will refuse it to make not null
   alter table public.clicks add column id integer not null default 0
2. **Drop default value from column**
   I am not exactly sure why it is needed because some manuals on internet omits this step but i was not able to make it work without this on DB2 9.7.3 LUW
   alter table public.clicks alter column id drop default
3. Now set column to always generated (**add the autoincrement**)
   alter table public.clicks alter column id set generated always as identity
4. Reorg table to make it writeable **(I didn't do this and it still works)**
   reorg table public.clicks
5. Now replace zeros with generated itentity values
   **update public.clicks set id = default**
6. **And optionally make id column primary key for table**
   alter table public.clicks add constraint pkey primary key(id)

And the liquibase code for it:

> defaultSchemaNames comes from spring properties which I defined like this. I don't know if there's a better way to get the schema but this one works also

```
# in application.properties I've set this
liquibase.parameters.defaultSchemaName=MY_SCHEMA_NAME
```

The `liquibase.xml`

```
    <property name="defaultSchema" value="${defaultSchemaName}" /> 

    <changeSet id="08.01.00" author="alex@mail.com">
        <dropPrimaryKey tableName="members" constraintName="pk_members_relation"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="08.01" author="alex@mail.com">
        <addColumn tableName="members">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT" defaultValue="0">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="member_type" type="varchar(100)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="08.02" author="alex@mail.com">
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="members" columnName="id"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="08.03" author="alex@mail.com">
        <addAutoIncrement tableName="members" columnName="id" columnDataType="bigint"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="08.04" author="alex@mail.com">
        <sql>
            UPDATE ${defaultSchema}.members SET id = default
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```